# Magento 2 Api to generate PayPal client token

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Hi
can anyone help me how to generate the client to PayPal Braintree in megento2. help me great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Call this Library > \Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapterFactory $bt_adapter in construct.

afterwards,

```
$bt_adapter = $this->bt_factory->create(); 
$value = $bt_adapter->generate();
```

That should generate a client token for you provided that you first made the config in admin for Braintree